# PowerShell module not found

Tags: azure, powershell, graph

We are planning to enforce azure app registration secret expiry time limit for that i am trying to run one PowerShell command but its not recognized and not able to found on which module this is available

Get-MgPolicyDefaultAppManagementPolicy

We have an option to use graph api, when trying from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer it taking to my default tenant where i need to test on B2B tenant

Any help on this please.

Comment: Are you talking about this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.signins/get-mgpolicydefaultappmanagementpolicy?view=graph-powershell-beta

Comment: Yes i have imported "Microsoft.Graph.Identity.SignIns" but still same issue, seems that module in not availble

Comment: The module needs to be installed on every client that you intend to run the command (`Install-Module`).

Answer (score 0):

The command "`Get-MgPolicyDefaultAppManagementPolicy`" is not a default PowerShell module command and it is provided by "Microsoft graph PowerShell" command modules. To run this command, you need to install `Msgraph` and import it.

```
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph -AllowClobber -Force
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph
```

*After that, I connected to* "MgGraph" *with a default tenant using* `connect-MgGraph` *command as shown below:*

[image]

**Note**: You need to provide the required scopes to grant admin consent under the app Api permissions to `connect-Mggraph`.

```
Scopes/API Permissions:"User.Read" & "Directory.ReadWrite.All"*
```

**Path:** `AzureAD -> App registrations -> API permissions`:

[image]

***Logging in to a different tenant other than the default one:***

```
connect-Mggraph -TenantID "xxxx" -scopes "User.ReadAll"
```

*While logging in, it redirects to the below screen, and you need to give the consent to read the Mg applications as shown in the image*.

[image]

***Connected MgGraph successfully:***

[image]

I ran `get-Mgcontext` command after a successful authentication and it worked:

[image]

If you want to get the list of mg users or applications or any information then you need to provide `Application.Read.All` delegated permission. Then only you will be able to retrieve all the `get` command results.

*Below is the script to connect with Mg graph using certificate authenticate with a client ID as well as required B2c tenant ID and was able to get the below details:*

```
$certificate = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My\$CertificateThumbprint
$pwd= "passowrdhere"
$Securepwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force $pwd
$certificate = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("C:\Users\jahnavi\Downloads\mycertwithkey.pfx",$Securepwd)
Connect-Graph -Certificate $certificate -TenantId "TenantID" -ClientId "clientID"
```

***Output:***

[image]

***I  got all the Mg users as well as applications list after all these steps:***

[image]

Refer [Github issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/tree/dev) for alternative ways to achieve this.